# MySQL - Query and group in a single row

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, merge

I have a set of data as below:

| EmployeeId | Salary_Basic | Salary_Transport | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E001 | 12000 | 3000 | 2018 |
| E002 | 9000 | 2000 | 2018 |
| E001 | 13000 | 3200 | 2019 |
| E002 | 10000 | 2400 | 2019 |
| E003 | 15000 | 5000 | 2019 |

What I want is below:

| EmployeeID | NetSalary_Year2018 | NetSalary_Year2019 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E001 | 15000 | 16200 |
| E002 | 11000 | 12400 |
| E003 | 0 | 20000 |

Can anyone suggest the sql query on MySQL please?

Thanks

Comment: Use conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Akina says, use "conditional aggregate".

For example:

```
select
  employeeid,
  sum(case when year = 2018 then salary_basic + salary_transport else 0 end) as net_salary_2018,
  sum(case when year = 2019 then salary_basic + salary_transport else 0 end) as net_salary_2019
from t
group by employeeid
```